Emulate surface tablet touch/Setup Vm ware as tabled vm windows 11
I want to setup a surface tablet but want to test all the things I want to do in a VM first. I did that but I have a problem with the touch controls. I don't have any touch inputs on my computer. How can I emulate touch inputs or set up vm ware to emulate mouse clicks as touch inputs? I want to test for example the touch keyboard behavior when clicking on text inputs etc.
Any idea on how to do that?
